# mysql aggregate function for varchar column

Tags: mysql, sum, aggregate, varchar2

I need to calculate the sum of one `column(col2)` , but the column has both numbers and text. How do I exclude the text alone before I use sum()? 
The table has around 1 million rows, so is there any way other than replacing the text first?
My query will be :

```
Select col1,sum(col2) from t1 group by col1,col2
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use MySQL built in **REGEXP** function.

to learn more visit : **https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html**

Or another way is using **CAST** or **CONVERT** function

to learn in detail : **https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html**

Hope this is helpful

Answer (score 2):

You can use regexp to filter the column:

```
Select col1,sum(col2) from t1  WHERE col2 REGEXP '^[0-9]+$' group by col1,col2
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean the number is at the beginning of the tex, the easiest way is simply to use implicit conversion:

```
Select col1, sum(col2 + 0)
from t1
group by col1, col2;
```

If `col2` starts with a non-numeric character, then MySQL will return `0`.  Otherwise, it will convert the leading numeric characters to a number.

Note that your query doesn't really make sense, because you are aggregating by `col2` as well as including it in the `group by`.  I suspect you really want:

```
Select col1, sum(col2 + 0)
from t1
group by col1;
```